# Cash Flow compounding

Tags: python

So I have this cash flow given: time= [0,1,2,3,4,5]cf = [100,25,-30,4,-12,60] and say that the pay period is semiannually and the compounding period is is years.

So I need to have the cash flow add the terms ([100+25,-30+4,-12,60]) in order to calculate the irr and npv from the modified cash flow: [125, -26, 48]

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: Do you have any code that you've tried already? This reads like a homework problem...

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results

Comment: @TomSwifty It's not a homework problem, per say, but it's part of a project. I have to read an excel file and whether its compounded (Y, M, Q) and when the PP is and I've hit a wall on this aspect. I have code for every other if/elif statement except the ones compounded multiple times throughout the year because i can't figure out how to  combine the values like i mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a simple list comprehension to sum each group of `n` values;

```
>>> cf = [100,25,-30,4,-12,60]
>>> n = 2
>>> [sum(cf[x:x+n]) for x in range(0, len(cf), n)]
[125, -26, 48]
```